# Node JavaScript timestamp in MySQL format

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, datetime

I'm using Node (Express.js) to update a MySQL database with the date now and it works fine but my code is a little repetitious.

```
var newYears = new Date();
var newMonths = new Date();
var newDays = new Date();
var newHours = new Date();
var newMinutes = new Date();
var newSeconds = new Date();
var yearNow = newYears.getFullYear();
var monthNow = newMonths.getMonth();
var dayNow = newDays.getDate();
var hourNow = newHours.getHours();
var minuteNow = newMinutes.getMinutes();
var secondNow = newSeconds.getSeconds();
var timeNow = yearNow + '-' + ( monthNow + 1 ) + '-' + dayNow + ' ' + hourNow + ':' + minuteNow + ':' + secondNow;
```

How few characters can the same result be achieved with?

Answer (score 1):

You could cut out some overhead like this:

```
   var basedate = new Date();
   var yearNow = basedate.getFullYear()
   var monthNow = basedate.getMonth();
   var dayNow = basedate.getDate();
   var hourNow = basedate.getHours();
   var minuteNow = basedate.getMinutes();
   var secondNow = basedate.getSeconds();
   var timeNow = yearNow + '-' + ( monthNow + 1 ) + '-' + dayNow + ' ' + hourNow + ':' +   minuteNow + ':' + secondNow;
```

Alteratively someone else might set up an array splitting the component parts of the Dateobject to save a few processor cycles, but unless you find yourself desperately needing to  cut down the execution time of your script, don't worry.

A good rule of thumb is if you can't quantify the speed-up, you shouldn't try to optimize for it. If it ain't broke...

On the other hand, you might like http://perlgolf.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If you wish to format the date correctly (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS instead of YYYY-M-D H:M:S as you have now), you can do this: `var timeNow = yearNow + '-' + String('00' + (monthNow + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + String('00' + dayNow).slice(-2) + ' ' + String('00' + hourNow).slice(-2) + ':' + String('00' + minuteNow).slice(-2) + ':' + String('00' + secondNow).slice(-2)`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var now = moment().add(1,'month').format("YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss A");
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r42jg/164/). You can use `var moment = require('moment');` if you want to use nodeJS. Rest of the code will be the same.